# context free grammar to deterministic finite-state automaton

Tags: automata, context-free-grammar

I have context free grammar `G=(V={S,A}, ∑={a,b}, R, S)` with R:

$\qquad\begin{align}
  S &\to aT \mid Sb \mid a \\
  T &\to aS \mid Tb \\ 
\end{align}$

Which I tried to convert to a deterministic finite-state automaton:`M=(Q={S,T}, ∑={a,b}, , q=S, F={S}`. So I came up with the following DFA:

[image: Grammar --> DFA]

With the idea that `S --> aT` in G is equal to `(S,a)=T` in M. However my Automaton seems to be wrong, because I can make a parsing tree from `aaabbb`, but in my automaton it ends up in T, which means it is not accepted. So I guess the following rule is NOT correct: `S --> Sb` equal to `(S,b)=S`.

How do I construct a correct DFA for the context free grammar G?

Edit 1: With the hint of @Brian M. Scott I got the following DFA:

[image: Adjusted G --> DFA]

So that it only accepts uneven a at the beginning and b>=0 at the end. Also no b between aa or a between bb is accepted (hence garbage node).

Edit 2: Added a, b transitions to the garbage State.

Comment: Worth noting that *not* every CFG has a corresponding DFA since the language of a CFG can be non-regular

Comment: With thanks to this website for easy creation of FA: http://madebyevan.com/fsm/

Comment: @NumesSanguis That website is amazing...it even exports to TikZ!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: Show that $G$ generates the language $\{a^{2m+1}b^n:m,n\ge 0\}$, and design a corresponding automaton. You're almost there: you have the wrong acceptor state, and you need to modify the $b$-transition at $S$ to handle correctly inputs that start with $b$ and inputs that have an $a$ *after* an acceptable input.

**Added:** By request I’m adding an outline of the analysis showing that $G$ generates the language $L=\{a^{2m+1}b^n:m,n\ge 0\}$. The first thing to notice is that in any terminal derivation the last step must apply the production $S\to a$: that’s the only one that does not produce a non-terminal symbol. Next, the other productions do not change the number of non-terminal symbols; since we start with one, we always have exactly one until we apply that final $S\to a$. The third important observation is that every $a$ except the last one produced is produced to the left of the non-terminal, while every $b$ is produced to its right. The first and third observations together show that every word generated by $G$ has the form $a^mb^n$ for some $m\ge 1$ and $n\ge 0$.

We next observe that there is no restriction on $n$: the productions $S\to Sb$ and $T\to Tb$ allow us to pump out any number of $b$s. However, we can only apply that final $S\to a$ if we have the non-terminal $S$, which means that for each application of $S\to aT$ we must have an application of $T\to aS$ to get back to $S$. That is, all of the $a$s in the final word except the one generated by $S\to a$ come in pairs, so altogether we must end up with an odd number of $a$s. We can have any number of pairs, including $0$, so the possible values of $m$ are the odd integers, the numbers $2k+1$ for $k\ge 0$.

Comment: I can see that $\{a^{2m+1}b^n:m,n\ge 0\}$ is indeed matching the Grammar, but how did you find this? Is it just guessing?

Also if I just change T to the acceptor state, what should I do about b when in state S? Because if keep `S -b-> S`, then `ba` is accepted, which it shouldn't? But if I don't have the `S -b-> S`, then it's not a DFA?

Comment: @NumesSanguis: It wasn't a guess: I analyzed the grammar and proved that it generates that language. My last comment was a bit careless, however: you do need to make some other changes. Specifically, you need a 'garbage' state that you reach if the first input is $b$.

Comment: @NumesSanguis: Looks good, though I prefer to include the $a$ and $b$ transitions from the garbage state to itself.

Comment: @NumesSanguis: I'm intending to try to find time to add it tomorrow. At the moment I'm away from my computer, typing on a portable device, and it would be a royal pain.

Comment: @NumesSanguis: Sounds good.